# Controlling a program via arm-none-eabi-gdb-py from Python

Tags: python, arm, gdb, embedded

I want to do something kinda weird to automate some processes involving embedded processors and other hardware.

I would like to control an ARM processor via GDB to run some tests by monitoring and changing some variables. I want to control the whole test from Python so I can synchronize other instruments/hardware when I trigger certain events on the processor.  I think arm-none-eabi-gdb-py would be very helpful in this, but how would that work in practice?

Do I start GDB from a Python subprocess, and then run Python from within GDB? It seems a bit convoluted, but Python for arm-none-eabi-gdb-py seems to require being run from within the GDB process. So I am a little confused how I would tie that into the outer 'test driver'.

Comment: there are easier ways to do this you realize and still have python from the host running the show.

Comment: Would love to hear other options! I have done similar over UART/CAN/etc. But this is intended to be a bit more flexible across devices that might not have an available coms line due to processor or hardware constraints...

Comment: well you cant get in runtime with gdb/swd unless you have runtime code that is talking to it, and if you had that then that is overkill.  you would be starting and stopping the processor to do that.  maybe there is something I dont know maybe through ETM.

Comment: you could abstract it then if they have comms use that if not then use another interface, but the bulk of the test fixture remains the same.

Comment: was thinking uart, but you covered that so...

Comment: It does seem possible, I haven't tried it yet, but this article addresses debug monitoring https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/cortex-m-debug-monitor. Seems a bit more complicated than I'd llike, but would really like to change/moniitor things on the fly via the debugger like I can do w/IAR and Keil.  Will need a separate question and some experimentation for that...

In the meantime I still have plenty of uses for a stop/start setup via Python/GDB that I'd like to straighten out as well.

Comment: yeah thats what I meant by runtime code a rom monitor you build into the project. and then you integrate the project with that and/or the rom monitor can poke at things.  Make it complicated enough and you can have gdb attach to the rom monitor, the issue still is that you need a communication interface to the rom monitor...uart, etc.  If you are back to stopping and starting with an OCD then the rom monitor doesnt buy you anything.